# Is there a program that will convert animated GIFs to MNG files?

Tags: software-rec, conversion, gif

I tried using the GIMP but the MNG plugin just crashes everytime I use it.

Is there a different (preferably free) program that does this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) and that seemed to do the trick:

```
convert animated_gif.gif animated_mng.mng
```

Comment: Wow - it converts back too, it's awesome. You saved me some time looking, +2 :)

Answer (score 2):

I usually prefer an online solution when I need to do something once in a while. This helps me in getting the task done without any hassle of downloading, installing, etc.

If you prefer the same and want to change some image(s) go to [change-images.com](http://www.change-images.com/convert-images.htm). This time I was looking for a GIF to MNG converter and this site worked like charm.

This site is an excellent resource - where you can not only convert images, but can also:

- Resize images
- Crop images
- Apply **several** effects and frames to images, etc.

without **any** hassle of downloading or installing a single thing.

The site provides a wide array of options for every task and the output quality is pretty good too. I highly recommend this site to everyone.